# Java -- The return type of a function is "String" but it can return both String and int data types

Tags: java, string, oop, integer

```
class Student {
    String name;
    int age;

    public void setInfo(String n, int a) {
        this.name = n;
        this.age = a;
    }

    public String getInfo() { // Notice the "String" data type in this function
        return (this.name + " " + this.age);  // "this.age" is a "int" data type but the function is supposed to be returning only "String" data type, right?
    }
}

public class OOPS {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Student s1 = new Student();

        s1.setInfo("John", 24);
        System.out.println(s1.getInfo());
    }
}
```

Here is the output: [Click me to see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UleFP.png)

The next thing I tried to do was replace "String" with "int" in the function.

Like this:

```
public int getInfo() {      
     return (this.name + " " + this.age); 
}
```

It throws this error: [Click me to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbs4L.png)

**The question is why is it so?**

Comment: Because `"John 24"` is a `String` not an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at it, @DawoodibnKareem. But, in the program, you can see I have saved the value "24" into an int datatype variable that is age.

Comment: Yes, I can see that, but your method is not just returning the age, it's returning `"John 24"`, which is NOT an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The string concatenation in your code:

```
return ( this.name + " " + this.age );
```

… implicitly generates a string from your `int` member field, `this.age`.

That is equivalent to a call to [`String.valueof`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(int)):

```
return ( this.name + " " + String.valueOf( this.age ) );
```

See [*Converting Numbers to Strings*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/converting.html) in the *Java Tutorials* provided by Oracle free of cost.